# AMD Driver not working on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, ati, updates, gpu

I've just updated Ubuntu to latest version using Update Manager. It upgraded my kernel to 3.2.0-30. As always after installing new kernel I've reinstalled GPU drivers but with no success.

AMD Driver (12.8) installer says that everything went ok, but running `glxinfo | grep 'GL version'` returns the following output:

```
OpenGL version string: 2.1 Mesa 8.0.2
```

My question is how can I install this drivers?

PS. Why does *Canonical* release update that doesn't support such a basic feature as GPU drivers are?

Here's output of running `fglrxinfo`:

```
display: :0.0  screen: 0
OpenGL vendor string: VMware, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 0x300)
OpenGL version string: 1.4 (2.1 Mesa 8.0.2)
```

Comment: It seems that doing ``sudo sh amd*.run`` and then installing driver from PPA (``sudo apt-get install fglrx``) resolved the issue. However, my graphics card is now listed as _HD 5000_ - it used to be _HD 6500/5700/5600 Series_ on AMD 12.6 Drivers.